# Time stamp with OData Query in CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, crm

I am working on CRM 2013. I have a java script web resource for my student Information system. Which takes a picture of a student and than save it as an attachment in notes.

What i am trying to do is that whenever a new picture of a student is taken, the profile should show that picture rather than the old one.
Following is my OData query that return all possible attachments against the record Id. However I only need the latest attachment against my record Id.

Should I be calculating the closest time stamp? or there are other ways to do it. Can you anyone please look into this problem and suggest a feasible approach.
Thanks in Advance

```
var temp= "/AnnotationSet?$select=DocumentBody,FileName,MimeType,ObjectId&$filter=ObjectId/Id eq guid'" + recordId + "'";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the following change in the query:

```
var temp= "/AnnotationSet?$select=DocumentBody,FileName,MimeType,ObjectId&$top=1&$orderby=CreatedOn desc&$filter=ObjectId/Id eq guid'" + recordId + "'";
```

Comment: you can also use "asc" for ascending order. Depends what you want.